# Валидность даты в JS

Tags: javascript, html, html5, дата

Преподователь придумал задание. Форма регистрации. Там идет ввод имени, выбор пола, дата рождения и кнопка. В задании сказано выводить ошибку если выбран мужской пол и возраст меньше 21 года, а если женский пол выбран, то при меньше 18-ти лет выводить ошибку.

Вот его задание
[image: Задание]

Я написал свой код, но он не доработан, кто может помочь его исправить, буду очень рад. Заранее спасибо!

```js
var form = document.getElementById('form'); //получаю форму по айди

        form.addEventListener('submit',function(e){ // ставлю на форму слушатель событий ра екшен submit(когба будет нажата кнопка с типом submit в форме), вторым аргументом идёт функция что сработает если произойдёт событие, в ней переменая e(название может быть любое), в которой всякие штуки для обраюотки события
            valid(form);//вызываю ту фукнции и передаю в неё форму
            e.preventDefault();//отменяю стандартное поведение события submit(обновление страници)
        })

        function valid (form) {
            
            var name = form.name.value; // тут я обьявил переменную имя и как я понял привязал её к кнопке
            var fail; // просто переменная в которую заносится ошибка
            
            
            
            
            if (name == "" || name==" ") 
                fail = alert('Вы не ввели свое имя');
            else if (document.getElementById('men').checked) {
               alert('Вы мужчина!'); 
            }
                
            //
            //
            else if (document.getElementById('women').checked) {
                alert('Вы женщина!');
            }
                
            //
            //
            
        }
```

```css
form {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form registration on JavaScript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>



    <form action="" method="post" name="form" id="form">
        
        <label for="name">Имя:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Введите своё имя" id="name" name="name">
        
        <br><br>
        
        <span>Выберите пол:</span>
        <input type="radio" id="men" name="status" value="men">
        <label for="men">Мужской</label>
        <input type="radio" id="women" name="status" value="women">
        <label for="women">Женский</label>
        
        <br><br>
        
        <label for="birthday">Введите ваш год рождения:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="День" id="bDay" name="birthday" size="2">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Месяц" id="bMon" name="birthday" size="2">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Год" id="bYear" name="birthday" size="4">
        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Проверить" name="submit" /> 
        
        
    </form>
    
    
    
    
    

     <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: У меня адекватно работает ввод имени и клики по кнопкам м/ж/не определен. Я и просил помочь доработать)

Comment: У Вас форма не соответствует заданию. У выбора пола должно быть два значения, а дата рождения - не один инпут, а три.

Comment: Ну я хотел сделать таким образом, ну если так легче, то я исправил код

Comment: Не то, чтобы легче, но зачем давать преподавателю лишний повод придраться? :)

Comment: За такие задания в Канаде препода либо бы быстренько убрали, либо пошёл бы под суд. Здесь - равенство полов

Comment: @SergeyNudnov это к сожалению или к счастью?  =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Риторический вопрос. :) Не могу объективно ответить - выпил ромчика, сижу жду посадку в Варадеро... Хоть в ИТ и немного женщин, но те, которые есть, не уступают мужчинам. Так что я - за равенство и всеобщую любовь! :)